# When to add an additional "service" or BLL layer?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

I've got a Web API controller such as:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("accounts", Name = "GetAccounts")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAccounts()
    {
        var query = Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery.Split('/')[2];

        var response = await Client.HTTPCLIENT.GetAsync(Client.HTTPCLIENT.BaseAddress + query);

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var readAsAsync = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
        if (readAsAsync == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var result = await readAsAsync;
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

My question is whether I should be simplifying the controller and pushing this logic into a new service/business logic layer?

My use case is to have this code run within a microservice on service fabric.

**Would it be redundant / unnecessary complexity to add another layer to this architecture, is there a benefit?**

Comment: You should use an another layer for complex logic, and large application, and for separate busness logic and presentation logic (like MVC)

Comment: When using service fabric you are probably looking for a micro services architecture. You can use a stateful service to store and retrieve data or a stateless service with a db as backend for example. or a stateless/stateful service for some business logic. It depends on your view of how big a microservice is. So tell me, why did you choose service fabric instead of, lets say, a web app?

Comment: in service fabric a common scenario is to run the api's on a node type with other specs that a node type which runs compute services. Without knowing you exact requirements it is hard to tell.

Comment: What logic? The "NotFound" logic?

Comment: @Mardoxx, no, specifically var response = await Client.HTTPCLIENT.GetAsync( ......... what if perhaps i had to make a call to a third party right after this line and aggregate and then return the results? in this case would i factor out all of this into a separate AccountService?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the only thing this controller does is make a call to another service and return the results. I don't see anything here that you can extract to another service.

I would always ask, what benefit are you getting out of having more services and at what cost? A round trip to a service is relatively expensive in terms of physical machine resource usage, development costs, and maintenance.